# VLC embeded in HTML: Could not open location; you might not have permission to open the file

Tags: html, web, vlc

I have a problem with playing videos through VLC web plugin embedded in HTML. Getting error:

> Could not open location; you might not have permission to open

No video getting played. My platform : Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32 bit.

I also use `sudo chmod 777 foldername` change the folder's permission,but it doesn't work either.